# Complex joins using Play Framework and Ebean

Tags: java, sql, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm using the PlayFramework and I'm really liking it. When I want to grab data from a table, for example I have a `user` table, I use the following syntax:

```
List<User> users = User.find.where().eq("email", email).findList();
```

My question is that when I get the user object, I have an `id` column. With that `id` value I can map to other tables and the `id`'s of those tables can be mapped to even more tables, so basic concept of joining across several tables. Is there any example or place I can read where it describes how to implement that with the above-like syntax?

I tried to find myself and couldn't, only way I can think of it at this point is to use straight sql with prepared statements which I'd rather not do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ellou' kalvish

`Relationships` between models are set with common JPA annotations like `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne`, `@OneToOne`, etc.

So if you have `User.java` model for user table and `Question.java` model for user's Question you can join them with `@OneToMany` (One `User` has Many `Question`s)

User

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String email;

    @OneToMany
    public List<Question> questions;
}
```

Question

```
@Entity
public class Question extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String question;
}
```

When you'll select a User in controller, Ebean will perform 'joins' by default and will fetch all user's questions as well:

```
User user = User.find.where().eq("email", email).findUnique();
List<Question> usersQuestion = user.questions;
```

By default Ebean fetches all object's properties and relations, so you don't need to create subqueries. Of course you can or even should select/fetch only the data that is required at the moment.

At the [official Ebean documentation page](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/documentation.html) you'll find quite good **Reference guide (pdf)**, general description of relationship is available in section `11.6.2 Relationships`.

In section `4.1.2 Query` there is example (second) which demonstrates how to get "partial" object with use of `select()` and `fetch()`

Comment: Hi Marcus, Thanks for your reply. I was looking at the manual just now, and i'm wondering if I could ask you a question on it...section 4.1.5 is describing the OneToMany, ManyToOne, etc. But how does it know which columns map? Say I have a column `myId` and that maps to a column `id` in another table, is there a way to specify that?

Comment: Ebean is cleaver enough to create appropriate DDL on model's change. Beware this in real case, but it's really good idea, to create other testing project and just learn it directly from Ebean

Comment: @KVISH I think what you are looking for is the JPA annotation @ JoinColumn where you can specify the name of the join column to use.